# Python program is suspended on Windows

Tags: python, windows, freeze, lockscreen, suspend

There is a program written in Python that uses `requests` and `threading libraries`, It all works in an endless loop, polling a specific service.

I compiled `.exe` file using `pyinstaller`. The essence of the problem is that after the screen is locked and after a while, the program is suspended.

Tell me what could be the problem.

Comment: Make sure that you are always specify [timeout](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts) in requests.

Comment: Why is it necessary in this case? The service I poll is fast enough and there are no problems with the Internet.